# Why cant one feel inner body parts?

Tags: brain

If we pour hot or cold water on skin then we feel it immediately. We respond to a small injection also.

But our body parts are doing a lot of work, for example, our lungs do inhale and exhale, our heart does beating, intestines does processing food, and liver, kidneys etc are also doing their work.

Even though a part is in my body, I dont know how it is until and unless I go through the Xray or some kind of scanning.

If a body part got disease like Cancer also, I cannot recognize it myself.

Does body parts have skin and wont they send signals to brain? If they wont send signal to brain then a cancer patient also  cant feel any pain any time?

Why one cannot feel their own inner body parts?

Comment: Kidney stones will quickly disavow you of any notion that your internal organs don't feel pain. So will bone cancer and dozens of other conditions. Questions here are expected to demonstrate some degree of prior research, so some of that should have been mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Feeling" is a perception generated in the brain. To feel something, the brain needs information about that part of the body, just like it needs information from the outside world to see or hear. That information comes from receptor neurons and other cells that communicate with neurons.

[Nociceptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nociceptor) are the receptors most associated with pain. There are nociceptors both in skin and in organs of a variety of types, but you can't feel anything where there are no receptors to feel something. There are different types of receptor cells more associated with touch.

There is also [sensory adaptation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neural_adaptation): your nervous system is mostly interested in things that change and mostly uninterested in things that stay the same. Constant feelings don't really draw your attention the way changes do, so organs that are doing something constant or rhythmic don't produce much of a feeling, just like a constant hum doesn't draw your attention after some time.

Comment: Which body parts does not have those receptors then?

Comment: @KalyanKumar It's complicated because some pain for example can be felt from adjacent tissues rather than the organ itself. I think you can get a lot from your own intuition, though: the things you can't feel are the ones you can't feel.

Comment: It may be sensible to add that *nociceptors do no adapt but increase their sensitivity* with constant input.